# How can I repair "Failed to start service WMS"

Tags: windows-10, event-log, windows-services

I'm receiving constantly this error on windows event viewer

```
Failed to start service WMS.  Program C:\Windows\wmu2\wininit.exe couldn't be launched. CreateProcess() failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image]

Any ideas what this error refers to and how to fix it?

I've ran sfc and dism with no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service named `WMS` and its module `C:\Windows\wmu2\wininit.exe` are aded by a program named `Waves_Complete_10.0.0.16_patch.exe`.

[image]
*(Image credits: hybrid-analysis.com)*

And, the service executable seems to have been deleted from your system, but the `WMS` Service remains as a residue.

**Remove the remnant service**

Open an admin Command Prompt window and run the following command:

```
SC.EXE DELETE WMS
```

This deletes the unwanted service.

**References**

- [ANY.RUN - Malware Analysis Results](https://any.run/report/eedc76c561874d0b54ed3ca58de88d39ad8d26904c5b613d19d1b33d87a13bc1/b44d95e9-128c-4ec3-b27b-7292d8825b9f)
- [File analysis results for 'Waves_Complete_10.0.0.16_patch.exe'](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/485d80e735f1dbdf17a8accd2e3f39ae4746bec14506ad74bba2fd65aae2c82c/5c2bed097ca3e1191e7d4789)
- [How to Delete a Service in Windows](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-remove-unwanted-service/)

Comment: Oh I see, I wonder how that could sneak in the system. All my software is licensed on the PC and I use most things downloaded from chocolatey. However I can see it download through otherwise seemingly legit trial software. I'm glad I could get rid of it, thank you :)

Comment: @gabtzi: Ok. It could be a legit program, and the 'malicious' indicator may be a false-positive in some cases. I've updated the answer now.